# Eclipse Glassfish 3.1 CREDENTIAL ERROR

Tags: eclipse-plugin, glassfish

I get the error "credential error" in eclipse indigo 3.7 with glassfish 3.1 when I try to start the server on Win xp. Glassfish starts normally from command line. When I start GS from eclipse I get:

[#|2011-09-29T17:30:58.386+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The log message is null.
java.rmi.NotBoundException: 127.0.0.1
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.unbind(RegistryImpl.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.stopAndUnexport(RMIConnectorStarter.java:314)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.shutdown(JMXStartupService.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService.shutdown(JMXStartupService.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService.access$000(JMXStartupService.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$ShutdownListener.event(JMXStartupService.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.stop(AppServerStartup.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.stop(GlassFishImpl.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.stop(GlassFishDecorator.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer.doExecute(StopServer.java:70)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopDomainCommand.execute(StopDomainCommand.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:383)

I assume that the problem is in RMI, the way the glassfish adapter in eclipse is trying to start GS. There is no port occupying 8686 which is the port throw which RMI is trying to get to GS. Is there a workaround. Help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just before. Now I started the domain like this:
%glassfish_installdir%\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
(There should also be an startmenu entry)
It finally works.